# Unable to play system sound iOS 7

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, audio, audiotoolbox

In my app I will play a system sound when it received a signal of specific frequency. To detect frequency I used the [PitchDetector](https://github.com/irtemed88/PitchDetector). Then I looked to the internet to see how to play the iOS system sound and I found [this](https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary). I wanted to play the sound called `sms_alert_circles.caf`, so in method `- (void)viewDidLoad` I wrote this code:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Modern/sms_alert_circles.caf"];
SystemSoundID soundID;
AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge_retained CFURLRef)fileURL,&soundID);
```

then in the method who detect the frequency of the audio signal I put this code:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(soundID);
```

but if I try to run this code on my iPhone nothing happened. It recognize the frequency, but it don't execute the sound, what's wrong in my code? Can you help me?

Obviously I turned on the sound of my device

Comment: check your phone's hard mute button

Comment: I edited now the question and the sound is turned on (the mute button is turned off)

Comment: are you recording anything like audio or voice?

Comment: can you confirm that the path you use to create the fileURL object actually has the file with permission to read it? My understanding is that as of iOS4 you must provide your own sound files. Unless the device is jail broken I don't believe you can access the file.

Comment: @iTroyd23: I'm using microphone to detect audio signals

Comment: @lucgian841 i too faced this problem while recording video. your sound enabling systems will not work if audio signals dectection was in process. i think so. please ensure that. disable audio detection and play audio and check again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe your path is wrong, it should be path to a file inside the app's bundle.

Add your `sms_alert_circles.caf` file to your xcode project. Check that file is in "Copy Bundle Resources" list in "Build Phases" of project. Then change following line:

```
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"/System/Library/Audio/UISounds/Modern/sms_alert_circles.caf"];
```

to

```
NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle]
                           pathForResource:@"sms_alert_circles.caf"
                           ofType:nil];
NSURL *fileURL = [NSURL URLWithString:soundPath];
```

Also you can try to use [AKSystemSound](https://github.com/IvanRublev/AKSystemSound) library to play sound via almost one line of code.